# How cloud based web proxy works (ex:Zscaler)?

Tags: proxy

1) How zscaler see the clients traffic from cloud and how it filters malicious traffic?

2)  How zscaler protects the web applications from external threats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How zscaler see the clients traffic from cloud and how it filters malicious traffic?

Because it is configured as a proxy and thus the client sends its web traffic there.

> 2) How zscaler protects the web applications from external threats?

zscaler is not a Web Application Firewall, i.e. it does not protect the web application but the client browsing the web. It is doing this by the usual range of techniques, i.e. blacklists, antivirus etc.

Comment: I think zscaler has a service running on the platform(Windows/Linux/Mac) which filters the client's web requests. I was wondering if there is a way for individual browsers to not send requests to zscaler service.

Comment: @nishant: While related this is not in the scope of the actual question. And it is more a question for ZScaler support, since it is about the specific details of a specific version of a proprietary closed source product.